# MS Access/SQL--Transitioning Columns to Rows for Dynamic Data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a document list that is updated periodically.  The list may have up to 5 associated doc numbers associated with it.  I need to generate a report that will have the primary document listed and the other 'sub documents' listed as well.

I basically need a table as show in the picture.  I attempted a UNION, but if the data is dynamic, I would also continually need to update the query.

Any help or direction with this concept would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'data is dynamic' - number of columns in source data changes? Is your document an Excel spreadsheet? If columns are missing, add them so the UNION will work. Or modify the UNION as you stated. Can't be too difficult since there are never more five associated docs. Otherwise, write VBA procedure that will INSERT records to 'temp' table.

Comment: Thank you.  I meant that the data will change weekly.  Basically, we have a less than desirable process with multiple databases of questionable quality.

Comment: I will have documents that will remain in the MR column , however, docs will be added and deleted over time.  MRRs will be added in the other column.   I am lost on the concept to run a query from one database (the output being repeats in Field 1 due to multiple different entries in field 2) and making it look like the above (right table).  I am actively pursuing more knowledge, but I appreciate your help along the way.

Comment: You say source data is 'dynamic', that MRR docs will be added and deleted. Do you want to retain all MRR docs in db for historical purpose? I am a little confused - which table is what the source data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see other solution but read the recordset row by row and insert the data into new table. PIVOT would not work in this case.

Comment: Thank you.  The process is really the problem, I am changing it slowly due to micro management.  I appreciate your time.